# Message in console on iOS 15: "Binding<String> action tried to update multiple times per frame."

Tags: xcode, swiftui, ios15

I have the following code:

```
struct Credential: Equatable {
    var username = ""
    var password = ""
}

enum Database {
    static var credential = Credential()
}

struct UsernamePasswordInput: View {
    @Binding var credential: Credential

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TextField("Username", text: self.$credential.username)
            SecureField("password", text: self.$credential.password)
        }
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}

struct Login: View {
    private var credential: Binding<Credential>

    var body: some View {
        UsernamePasswordInput(credential: self.credential)
    }

    init() {
        self.credential = Binding<Credential>(
            get: {
                Database.credential
            }, set: { newValue in
                Database.credential = newValue
            }
        )
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Login()
    }
}
```

When you run this code from Xcode 13.0 on an iOS 15 device, the message `Binding<String> action tried to update multiple times per frame.` appears in the Xcode console. This happens whenever you type a character into either the `TextField` or the `SecureField`. The message does not appear on iOS 13 or 14 devices.

I know I can solve it by just using a `@StateObject` but the above code reflects the structure of a larger project. My question is: is the Xcode message somehow indicative of a problem? Is the code above principally incorrect somehow?

Comment: It is likely that custom init. SwiftUI does not do well with those. It can decide to reload the entire View whenever it wants. Instead of a custom binding just use the regular binding. It seems like an oxymoron to have a private variable hacky updated by the outside.

Comment: @loremipsum FYI: I moved the creating of the binding in the Login view to the instantiation of the UsernamePasswordInput view, and that didn't remove the message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a possible safe workaround - use inline separated binding for each text field:

```
struct UsernamePasswordInput: View {
    @Binding var credential: Credential

    var body: some View {
        Group {
            TextField("Username", text: Binding(
                get: { credential.username },
                set: { credential.username = $0 }
                ))
            SecureField("password", text: Binding(
                get: { credential.password },
                set: { credential.password = $0 }
                ))
        }
        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
    }
}
```

Tested with Xcode 13 / iOS 15

Comment: Yup, that was it. Obviously, the difference is that my code binds to a struct, and your code binds to a string of that struct. Can you explain why it was wrong to bind to a struct outside the view?

Comment: I had my text fields inside a UIViewControllerRepresentable and I was getting the same warnings in console even though i wasn't binding to a struct but a single value. Your solution worked for me too. I'm also interested as to why it was a problem before : )